# How do I make the fancy H for the set of quaternions, like the fancy R for real numbers?

Tags: symbols, typography

Sorry for the noob question, I'm writing a paper on quaternions for a linear algebra class and I decided it would be a good time to start learning LaTex.

Comment: Well the "fancy R" (a blackboard bold R) is `\mathbb{R}` (requires `amssymb` or `amsfonts`). The "fancy H" is the same, `\mathbb{H}`. If you are using something like `\R` that's a custom command, it's not a pre-defined command. You can define a custom command for the blackboard bold H as well, but I would not recommend making it `\H` because that is already used for the double acute accent as in Erdős (`Erd\H{o}s`). Best go for something `\newcommand{\qtrnions}{\mathbb{H}}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You have two possibilities: `\mathbb{H}` for blackboard bold, or `\mathbf{H}` for the old-style (real) boldface.

Comment: There's also Unicode ℍ, requires `XeLaTeX`, for example

Answer (score 1):

Here's the `XeLaTeX` (or `LuaLaTeX`) way by typing the unicode sequence (or copying over from some char table/text).

The ℍ character has the code U-210D.

Of course, the used font must support this character.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}% Just as an example


\begin{document}
Use for example ℍ (DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL H), i.e. U-210D for this. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well I am currently using Share LaTex, so how would I get that symbol in the middle of a paragraph?

Comment: Because that is the H I am looking for.

Comment: @SpencerEwingFriedman: Sigh, `ShareLaTeX`.... :-(  See https://www.sharelatex.com/project/597e670b712c4a5c56e3ca39

Comment: It says that I do not have permission to load that page

Comment: @SpencerEwingFriedman: Sorry, try again, please

Comment: Thank you for the help, however when I put the \usepackage in the right place then copied the line of code with the H it just compiles into fj

Comment: @SpencerEwingFriedman: Have you used `XeLaTeX`?